# Bluetooth inactive error in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bluetooth, chrome-book

I'm trying to take data from a bluetooth device in a Linux terminal, but running into problems. When I run this command:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

I get this error:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabl>
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/service.d
             └─zzz-lxc-service.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

I've tried several [fixes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts) from other forums, but none work. I tried running

```
sudo modprobe btusb
```

But get this error:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module btusb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.108-18910-gab0e1cb584e1
```

This is the version of Linux I'm running:
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: Linux 5.15.108-18910-gab0e1cb584e1
Architecture: arm64

I'm trying to run a python script that takes in data from bluetooth devices. I'm using the Bleak package and get this error:

```
bleak.exc.BleakDBusError: [org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Contents of `systemctl cat bluetooth.service`:

```
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service

# /run/systemd/system/service.d/zzz-lxc-service.conf
[Service]
ProtectProc=default
ProtectControlGroups=no
ProtectKernelTunables=no
NoNewPrivileges=no
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It seems like a container system (LXC = Linux Containers) may be affecting the `bluetooth.service` available to you. What is the full output of `systemctl cat bluetooth.service`? Please edit your original question and paste that information in there. This is a service that needs hardware access; are you trying to run it inside a container?

Comment: I updated it with the output. thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel version `5.15.108-18910-gab0e1cb584e1` is not a standard Debian kernel.

Googling for that kernel version string suggests this might be a Chromebook... and the presence of `zzz-lxc-service.conf` suggests you are not running on a straight Linux OS, but perhaps in a ChromeOS's Linux container. It certainly seems to lack the `btusb` kernel module, which is the driver for most common USB Bluetooth adapters.

If this is hosted on a ChromeOS, then I have some bad news. According to [Running Custom Containers Under ChromeOS](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/containers_and_vms.md#can-i-access-hardware-e_g_usb_bluetooth_serial) document, Bluetooth access is not available to Linux containers running under ChromeOS:

> Can I access hardware (e.g. USB/Bluetooth/serial)?
>
> USB support for some devices, including Android devices and serial devices, is available via ChromeOS Settings. **Direct Bluetooth access is not available** but you could use the Web Bluetooth API with a web server running in Crostini.

That would explain why your kernel configuration does not include the `btusb` module: if you cannot use it within the container anyway, it makes no sense to build it into a setup that is designed to be used within a container.